# AS3 Regular expression

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Any of you gone through this task? Please tell me a solution.

I have to extract video id alone from youtube url : `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls8ppLu72NQ&feature=popular`

From this i need only **Ls8ppLu72NQ** How can i extract it. I know i can use string replace but is there a way to
  extract it easily with regex.

Url can be all these formats

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls8ppLu72NQ&feature=popular`
   `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls8ppLu72NQ`

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch/Ls8ppLu72NQ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
watch(?:\/|(?:\?|.*&)v=)(\w+)
```

The result will be in the 1st capture group.

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/7J9FSgwBMf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Aillyn

Its worked for me.

I made it in the following way
**

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /watch(?:\/|(?:\?|.*&)v=)(\w+)/ig;   
var str:String = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?&vx=123&v=Ls8ppLu72NT";
var result:Object = myPattern.exec(str);
trace(result[1]);
```

**